# Ternary if statement ? if true do nothing

Tags: apex

Is there a way to say do nothing in a ternary if statement? Currently i have it set to just equal itself on true. Would it be better programming to do this another way?

Example:

```
Id userID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
userID = (userID != null) ? userID : UserInfo.getUserId();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't using ternary if, but it achieves the result that you are looking for and I think it's clear to understand...

```
Id userID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
if (userID == null) userID = UserInfo.getUserId();
```

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. If there is only one outcome then there would be no need to use a ternay if, seeing as how there is no need to do an else. You helped me realize my mistake